# Varnish not caching

Tags: linux, reverse-proxy

I am running a web server on my rasberryPi and just managed to install varnish with this tutorial http://www.weedpi.com/how-to/install-va ... pberry-pi/

I went to this site http://www.isvarnishworking.com/ and checked if my Varnish is working and got a message: Yes! Sort of! Varnish appears to be responding at that url, but the "Age" header is less than 1.
This means that either, 1) you checked right when Varnish cleared it's cache for that url, or 2) for whatever reason Varnish is not actually serving the content for that url from cache.

So my problem is that Varnish is answering correctly but it is not serving pages from cache... How can I fix this ? I have no idea because normal Varnish commands are not working :/

Comment: Sorry if I'm underestimating your knowledge, but have you configured what you want it to cache? Or you just did what's written in that tutorial? I made mistake thinking having vcl file means it is configured to cache everything. Silly me - couldn't be further from truth :)
Don't know if it'll help you but here's the page with varnish example vcl files https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/VCLExamples

Comment: I have succesfully configured Varnish in computer with 2gb ram, but raspberry Pi has only 512mb ram and I pretty much just followed the tutorial... Maybe I should read more about the vcl file if that defines what and how much is cached.

Comment: Yes, I haven't been talking about memory allocation, but backend configuration and cacheing polices. Note: PLEASE provide some feedback here - marking comments as helpful, or comment/answer this question yourself. To conclude, it's probably an overkill, but here's an interesting... let's call it "tutorial" about Varnish: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JEF6_XC-2ZU

Comment: Well I like to know about these things might be just the thing that I am looking for, will give it a try. I just started my adventure in superuser.com how can I vote comments ? Can't see a plus button ?